# Numpy Neural networks cost calculation: result changes after first run

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network, data-science

In python3.7, I am having an issue with my neural network cost calculation.
When I first run `compute_cost_nn` I get the correct cost `0.28762916516131887` but on all subsequent runs, the cost changes to `0.3262751145707298`, which is quite annoying.
It looks like the issue comes from my `params`; if I reload them every time just before calculating the cost, it works fine. But I can't rerun the function with different parameters and get correct costs without running the whole script again.

The neural network has 400 input units, 1 hidden layer with 25 units, and 10 output units.

Here are the inputs:

```py
data = loadmat("ex4data1.mat")
y = data['y']
X = data['X']
X = np.c_[np.ones((X.shape[0], 1)), X]

weights = loadmat("ex4weights.mat")
Theta1 = weights['Theta1']
Theta2 = weights['Theta2']
params = np.r_[Theta1.ravel(), Theta2.ravel()]
```

Matrix shapes:

```
>> X: (5000, 401)
>> y: (5000, 1)
>> Theta1: (25, 401)
>> Theta2: (10, 26)
>> params: (10285,)
```

And cost function:

```py
def compute_cost_nn(params,
                    input_layer_size,
                    hidden_layer_size,
                    num_labels,
                    X, y, lambda_):

    m = len(y)

    # Retrieve Theta1 and Theta2 from flattened params
    t1_items = (input_layer_size + 1) * hidden_layer_size
    Theta1 = params[0:t1_items].reshape(
        hidden_layer_size, 
        input_layer_size+1
        )
    Theta2 = params[t1_items:].reshape(
        num_labels, 
        hidden_layer_size+1
        )

    # transform y vector column (5000x1) with labels 
    # into 5000x10 matrix with 0s and 1s
    y_mat = np.eye(num_labels)[(y-1).ravel(), :]

    # Forward propagation
    a1 = X
    z2 = a1 @ Theta1.T
    a2 = sigmoid(z2)
    a2 = np.c_[np.ones((m,1)), a2]
    z3 = a2 @ Theta2.T
    a3 = sigmoid(z3)

    # Compute cost
    func = y_mat.T @ np.log(a3) + (1-y_mat).T @ np.log(1-a3)
    cost = func.trace()
    t1reg = (Theta1[:,1:].T @ Theta1[:,1:]).trace()
    t2reg = (Theta2[:,1:].T @ Theta2[:,1:]).trace()
    cost_r = -1/m * cost + lambda_/(2*m) * (t1reg + t2reg)

    # Gradients (excluding Theta0)
    d3 = a3 - y_mat
    d2 = (d3 @ Theta2[:,1:]) * sigmoid_gradient(z2) #5000*25

    Delta1 = d2.T @ a1
    Delta2 = d3.T @ a2
    Theta1_grad = 1/m * Delta1
    Theta2_grad = 1/m * Delta2

    # Gradient regularization
    Theta1[:,1] = 0
    Theta2[:,1] = 0
    Theta1_grad = Theta1_grad + lambda_/m * Theta1
    Theta2_grad = Theta2_grad + lambda_/m * Theta2

    return cost_r, Theta1_grad, Theta2_grad
```

And I get the cost by running:

```py
compute_cost_nn(params, 400, 25, 10, X, y, 0)[0]
```

First run: `0.28762916516131887`
Then: `0.3262751145707298`

Any tips greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Whoa, there's a new operator in Python! Late to the party, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested your code with dummy data, but from a quick glance at it, it seems you are importing the weights from a `.mat` (MATLAB) file. MATLAB stores the elements of arrays in column-major order (a.k.a Fortran style order), while Python is row-major (C-style order).

Hence when you first `ravel()` your weights, Numpy will flatten the array assuming C-style order.
Same story when you reshape the ravelled weights in your functions.
You can add the order as an argument to either functions, so:

```py
params = np.r_[Theta1.ravel(order='F'), Theta2.ravel('F')]
```

Should fix your issue.

Maybe have a read about row- and column-major order if you never came across it:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order